# How to convert 32 bytes to a 256bit integer?

Tags: c#, c++, sha256

I'm busy porting a c++ app to c#.
The app contains code that hashes data into a 256bit integer.

```
uint256 res = data->GetHash();
```

The GetHash function looks like this:

```
uint256 hash;
SHA256((unsigned char*)&data, sizeof(data), (unsigned char*)&hash);
return hash;
```

In c# I use the BigMath library but get a different value to the c++ app.
My c# code looks like this:

```
SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();

byte[] bytes = GetByteArray(data);

Int256 hash256 = BigMath.Utils.ExtendedBitConverter.ToInt256(sha256.ComputeHash(bytes), 0, true);
```

The c++ apps' `uint256` type uses 8 x 32bit ints, while I see the c# BigMath library uses 4 x 64bit ints.

This shouldn't cause a problem right? Surely the output should be the same from both?
I'm expecting that both sha256 and 256bit int standards will be the same across languages?

Comment: Watch out for endianness. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Why convert the hash to an integer instead of treating it as a byte array? This locks you to a specific hash length without any obvious gain.